# Measure and volume zero in compact spaces

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $E\subset R^n$ be a compact space. I want to prove that $E$ has Jordan-volume zero if and only if it has measure zero.

The left to right implication is trivially true even for non-compact spaces, so I am left with the other.

For that purpose, I think I need to start by picking a numerable cover by rectangles whose total volume is less than $\epsilon$. Now, if rectangles were open sets, then I could appeal to compactness to get a finite subcover with volume less than $\epsilon$. But they are not.

So I thought of picking the interior of the rectangles of the cover, and then somehow filling the gaps I've created with new rectangle interiors, procuring to only add numerable many. Thus I would be left with an open cover and I could apply compactness.

Is my approach correct? How do I proceed otherwise?

Comment: If you look at the interior of the rectangles then filling those gaps is a problem. Instead you could replace your rectangles by _open_ rectangles just a teensy bit larger than the originals...